# VIM How do I search for a <XX> single byte representation

Tags: vim

When I cut and paste from a Word document into VIM, quotes get translated into a-circumflex followed by <99>, where the <99> is a single byte representation. (Which I know because when I move to it, typing a single 'l' moves me right to the over all four characters).

I want to do search and replace, and I know enough to find the a-cirumflex digraph using control-K a>, but I can't figure out how to search for the <99>, and searching for the literal /<99> doesn't work.

So I really have two questions:

What help topic should I consult in vim to learn about what sort of a beast the <99> is (since it doesn't seem to be a digraph) (or maybe it IS a digraph and I'm missing something)?

How do I search for a single character represented by <99>?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

Put your cursor over the character, type **`ga`** and you will see the hexadecimal representation of the character, then you can replace it with:

:%s/\%xNN//g

Where **NN** is the hex code of the character.

Comment: great! i've been wondering for some time how to do this.... The only comment I can make is that this answer simply deletes the hex character. For those not that familiar with vi, you can replace it with whatever you like by doing something like this  :%s/\%xNN/REPLACEMENT/g

Comment: for some reason I had to search with \%U for 0200b character.  
If your pattern doesn't match, try this:
:%s/\UNN//g

Comment: and to just search for the character after you know it's hexadecimal representation, type this /%xNN

Comment: ga may pad the value with leading zeros, ie: 00nn.  In the search/replace expression you should omit those zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Is'n it relates [vim shows question mark instead of character](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=397162) ?

It could be unicode character 0x0099, which has no graphical representation.

How to insert unicode - "u0099 in INSERT mode inserts a character with the unicode
value 0x0099." (from [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-90866.html))

Answer (score 0):

@CMS detailed searching directly for the character value.  If the character is a word by itself (or you can add spaces quickly to make it so), you can also cursor over the character and type ***** -- which will search forward for the closest word to the cursor (**#** to go backwards).